# Get-ADUser shows much fewer info on my pc than on coworker's pc

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have no opportunity to install RSAT so I just imported

- Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.dll and
- Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.resourses.dll.

Such commands as `Get-ADUser` work, but I get much less information as an output. Here are screenshots of how many lines they get and how few I get:

Part of my coworker's output

[image: part of my coworker's output]

All the output I get

[image: all output i get]

**UPD: I and my coworker both use admin accounts with the same privileges.**

Comment: Do you both have have just the dll's or does the machine with more output have RSAT installed and the other does not, or what's the difference there.

Comment: RSAT is installed on coworker's pc

Answer (score 0):

This is actually something I ran into recently, and the solution is rather simple.

Close Powershell and reopen it as Administrator.

When Get-ADUser returns less information, it is almost always a permission issue.

Comment: My fault. I haven't mentioned that I and my coworker run it as administrator. We have tried to use the same admin account, but they get a lot more info than I get.

Comment: I guess the problem is in my pc cause we have tried to run it from my pc and coworker's one using the same account. As a result it works fine on their pc and sends much less on mine

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the difference is between your pc's then. You could try the command enter-pssession <servername> to connect to the domain controller and run it then, but other than that, not sure. I'll keep the answer here for others though.